# Create EventReceiver For remote Sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, event-receiver

I have given a url of Sharepoint Site which is hosted somewhere on remote server. And I am trying to write a event receiver for library on that site BUT when i try to  specify that url of site (on remote machine) , visual studio(2010) giving following error.
[image: erroe after entering the url]

after some search.. I think we can not write eventreceiver to sharepoint(2010) site on remote machine/server.

Please suggest somthing if there are another possibility.

Comment: Plz anybody tell the possibility !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

write your code on local site , then get the `wsp` package and deploy it on remote server

Comment: thank you for your reply. I know the process u have maintian above but I have only the url of hosted sharepoint site. So accourding to you I should get the machine(loclhost) on which that site was developed. Plz answer if i am right.

Comment: yes you should have access to this machine as "farm administrator" to be able to deploy WSPs